# Get variables/properties from a Activator.CreateInstance object?

Tags: c#

Here is the code I have :

```
public class Test
{
   string a;
   int b;
}

public class Test2
{
   string c;
   string d
   int e;
}
```

I'm compiling it to a DLL and extracting both Classes with :

```
var library = Assembly.LoadFrom(libraryPath);
IEnumerable<Type> types = library.GetTypes();
```

and then "foreach type in types", I'd like to get a list of my variables but don't know how to do it... I'm trying :

```
var lib = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
Type myType = lib.GetType();
IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(myType.GetProperties());

foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
{
    // Do something with propValue
}
```

"props" is empty all the time...

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you show are NOT properties but are Fields - so you need to call [`myType.GetFields()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getfields.aspx). For private fields etc. you will need to call with the appropriate [`BindingFlags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx).

Comment: humm ok, I get it :)
You're the first so I give you the acceptance !

Comment: @GuillaumeCogranne Now you are confusing me... if you want to access Properties use `GetProperties`... if you want to access Fields use `GetFields`...

Comment: My example was not my code, it was a simpler version. In my "real" code, my fields are not string/ints but other objects ! So... as far as I understood, I HAVE to use Field to get my objects, but then I think that I have to use Properties to get string/ints/etc.. in my Fields, right ?

Comment: @GuillaumeCogranne IF you have a field which is an object... then you need to call `GetType()` on the object and then you need to either call `GetProperties` or `GetFields` which depends on the object and on what you are after... ask a new question with the more complex "real" code (you can even link to this question)... don't forget to upvote/mark as accepted any helpful answer...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037391/dependency-objects-properties-from-a-dll here is my "final" question ;)

Answer (score 8):

Your classes don't specify any properties. They specify private fields. That means:

- You need to call `GetFields`, not `GetProperties`
- You need to specify `BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance` so that you are provided with the *non-public* instance fields

Alternatively you could change your classes to have public properties, of course.

Comment: Ok, let's now consider that my Field is a Class with a certain number of properties. How can I acces to them through "FieldInfo" ?

Comment: @GuillaumeCogranne: You'd first get the value of the field, the get the properties of the field type using `Type.GetProperties`, then fetch the value of each property with respect to that value using `prop.GetValue(fieldValue, null)`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess u meant

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
FieldInfo[] fields = myType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
{
    object value = field.GetValue(instance);

    // Do something with field value...
}
```

To get the list of fields you need to use GetFields.

To get the list of methods you need to use GetMethods.

To get the list of properties you need to use GetProperties.

To get the list of events you need to use GetEvents.

And... you don't need to create a List in this case, are you sure u need to create a list? You can just work with the array, it returns always a copy.

Comment: Ok, let's now consider that my Field is a Class with a certain number of properties. How can I acces to them through "FieldInfo" ?

Comment: As I said, to access properties you must use PropertyInfo. To access fields you must use FieldInfo.

Comment: Yep, but I gotta access properties in a Field !
And myField.GetType().GetProperties() is empty...
Here is a more detailed version of my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037391/dependency-objects-properties-from-a-dll